# Is "ultracompact" taken?

Tags: set-theory, soft-question, terminology, large-cardinals

Almost-huge cardinals are characterizable in terms of coherent towers of supercompactness measures, with a certain property of the direct limit model (see Kanamori's book).  A useful large cardinal hypothesis between almost-huge and huge is the assertion that a cardinal has an almost-hugeness towers of unbounded height.  The most natural name for this would be "super-almost-huge," but that sounds too awkward to me.  I was thinking "ultracompact" might be good because of its affinity with supercompactness.  So my question is, is this a bad choice of terminology for some reason, or did someone already give a name to this hypothesis?

Comment: Sometimes people say that $\kappa$ is super-almost-huge to mean that $\kappa$ is almost huge with arbitrarily large almost-hugeness targets, that is, witnessed by almost hugeness embeddings $j:V\to M$ where $j(\kappa)$ is as large as you like.

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent to the towers being unbddly high.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure what you meant by that. In this case, I would say that it is fairly standard terminology, and widely understood.

Comment: Re: "ultracompact" itself, a quick google search reveals no use of the term in set theory. In point-set topology, however, an "ultracompact space" is a space such that given any ultrafilter $U\in\beta\mathbb{N}$ and any sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, there is some $x\in X$ such that $ \forall O\subseteq X\text{ open, } x\in O\implies \{j\in\mathbb{N}: x_j\in O\}\in U.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the super-almost-huge terminology is fairly widely used with this meaning, so that $\kappa$ is super-almost-huge if for every $\theta$ there is an almost hugeness embedding $j:V\to M$ with critical point $\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)\gt\theta$.

This terminology aligns with the similar terminology for [superhuge](http://cantorsattic.info/Huge#Superhuge) cardinals and [super $n$-huge](http://cantorsattic.info/Huge#Super_n_huge) cardinals, which seems to be fairly established. In addition, there are the [super high-jump](http://boolesrings.org/perlmutter/files/2013/04/ChartForWebSite.jpg) cardinals, and [super-almost-high-jump](http://boolesrings.org/perlmutter/files/2013/04/ChartForWebSite.jpg) cardinals, which follow the same idea of having these embeddings for arbitrarily large targets. For this reason I would recommend against introducing a new terminology without very good reason.

(Meanwhile, note that "hypercompact" is already taken, as you can see on Norman Perlmutter's chart of large cardinals near the high-jump cardinals (linked above), although to my knowledge "ultracompact" is still  available as a large cardinal name.)

Comment: The two last links to the picture https://boolesrings.org/perlmutter/files/2013/04/ChartForWebSite.jpg are broken. (Maybe somebody knows what post they are taken from and they are still available somewhere online.) However, the picture is available [in the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170208174317if_/http://boolesrings.org/perlmutter/files/2013/04/ChartForWebSite.jpg).